# MooTools custom drag event

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools-events

Is there anyway to define a drag event in MooTools using the `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `mousemove` events. I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
$('#knob').addEvent('drag', function (e) {
    // Drag event code goes here...
});
```

Comment: Can you explain better what you want? Did you check the demos in the mootools.net website? you can add code to the events already in the Class: __http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Drag.Drop__. You have also many events in the Class here: __http://mootools.net/docs/more/Drag/Drag#Drag__

Comment: Sorry I probably should have explained better. HTML5 defines a drag and drop API and I figured the best way to learn about MooTools and events is try to mimic the functionality of it. See answer below, this is what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **[Dragging](http://jokes.cc.com/funny-news---politics/bdbm37/dragging-their-feet)**

Although Mootools has implemented all you need for [drag, drop, slide and similar effects](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Drag/Drag), writing your own event is a good way to learn how events work. Here is an example of how to add additional custom event by using the [Element.Events Object](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event#Element-Events).

Effect starts on mousedown event that registers mousemove event. When dragging is over mouseup event is fired that removes the mousemove event listener.

Since it can happen that mouse leaves the box (mouseup is not fired to clean up), mouseout event is added also.

At every step of the effect, `drag` event handler is launched with the original event object passed as argument, You can see the type of the original event with `console.log( e.type );`

```
window.addEvent( 'domready', function() {;

    Element.Events.drag = {

        // the function that will get fired when the custom event is added
        onAdd: function() {

            this.addEvents({
                mousedown: function(e) {
                    this.store( 'x', e.page.x - this.getPosition().x );
                    this.store( 'y', e.page.y - this.getPosition().y );

                    this.addEvents({ 
                        mousemove: function(e) {            
                            this.setPosition({
                                x: e.page.x - this.retrieve( 'x' ), 
                                y: e.page.y - this.retrieve( 'y' )
                            });

                            this.fireEvent( 'drag', e );
                        },
                        mouseout: function(e) {
                            this.fireEvent( 'mouseup', e );
                        }
                    });
                },
                mouseup: function(e) {
                    this.removeEvents( 'mousemove' );
                    this.removeEvents( 'mouseout' );
                    this.fireEvent( 'drag', e );
                }

            });
        },

        // the function that will get fired when the custom event is removed
        onRemove: function() {
            this.removeEvents( 'mousedown' );
            this.removeEvents( 'mouseup' );             
        }
    };

    $('draggable').addEvent( 'drag', function( e ) {
        console.log( e.type );
    });


    // $('draggable').removeEvents( 'drag' );

});
```

A few good articles about Mootools events:

- **[mootools.net](http://mootools.net/blog/2011/03/28/events-with-mootools-element-class-delegation-and-pseudos/)**
- **[ryanflorence.com](http://ryanflorence.com/mootools-events/)**

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I'm still a little unclear on how the onAdd() function works. Basically when does onAdd() get called and what does this.store() do?

Comment: [Mootools store](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:store), [onAdd](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event#Element-Events) is called when the custom event starts ( condition is true )